# How to retrieve second resultset from DataReader to Datatable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an sp that brings back two sets of results. I need to put both of these in a datatable and convert them into a datamodel.

How can I get the second set of results?

```
 SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
                ce.Database.Initialize(force: false);    
                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetJournal", connection);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;                  

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                var dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataTable.Load(reader);
                List<Header> headerList = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(values =>
                                                                   new Header
                                                                   {
                                                                       HeaderId = values.Field<Int32>("HeaderId").ToString()                                                                   
                                                                   }).ToList();

                myList1 = headerList;
                myList2 = detailList; <_---- I need to populate detail list
```

Also is naming all of the fields explicitly the most efficient way to load this list? Is there some sort of serialization that I can do instead? I can have tables up to 500 columns

Comment: if (reader.NextResult()) { .... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the reader is not closed you can load the further tables. If you have multiple results I suggest you to populate a `DataSet`, which can contain multiple `DataTable` instances:

```
public static DataSet ToDataSet(IDataReader reader)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    while (!reader.IsClosed)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(reader);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    }

    return ds;
}
```